# Divide Numbers from Input and Print Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

So I have two numbers which I want to use for calculations. 
I am using following HTML

```
<label>Personen</label>
<input type="number" id="personen" /><br />
<label>Kilometer</label>
<input type="number" id="kilometer" /><br />
<label>Output</label>
<input type="text" id="output" readonly /><br />
```

and the following jQuery

```
var $neu = $("#output");
var $kilometer, $personen;
var $neu = $kilometer/$personen;
$("#kilometer").keyup(function() {
    var kilometer = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $kilometer.val(kilometer);
})
$("#personen").keyup(function() {
    var personen = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $personen.val(personen);
})
```

But unfortunately I am not able to divide the two numbers from the input. What did I miss?

There is also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9fUf/57/

Comment: remove `$` from variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want, I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/g9fUf/59/

```
$("#kilometer").keyup(function() {
    var kilometer = parseFloat($("#kilometer").val());
    var personen = parseFloat($("#personen").val());
     $("#output").val(kilometer/personen);
});
$("#personen").keyup(function() {
    var kilometer = parseFloat($("#kilometer").val());
    var personen = parseFloat($("#personen").val());
    $("#output").val(kilometer/personen);
});
```

You may refine this solution to display result only when `kilometer` and `personen` are defined and float numbers. You might also group the two functions in one JQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

`$kilometer` and `$personen` are variable names and not jQuery objects use the assign operator to set the values

`$kilometer=kilometer;`

And even though it is allowed, I would advise to remove the dollar sign from the variable names. In more complex functions it is harder to distinguish between variable names and jQuery functions.

Comment: See the answer of M. Page giving you a complete solution.